# Multivariate polynomial division in sage

Tags: python, sage, polynomials

I try to do a simple division of polynomials in two variables using sage.
Unfortunately, I get an unexpected result, as is illustrated in the code below.
I tried several different ways to instantiate the ring and its variables, but
the result stays the same. Using the %-operator to get a rest of a division yields the same results. Any ideas?

```
R, (x, y) = PolynomialRing(RationalField(), 2, 'xy').objgens()
t = x^2*y^2 + x^2*y - y + 1
f1 = x*y^2 + x
f2 = x*y - y^3

(q, r) = t.quo_rem(f1)
print "quotient:", q, "reminder:", r
assert q == x and r == x^2*y-x^2-y+1

(q, r) = r.quo_rem(f2) # error, expected q = x, r = -x^2+x*y^3-y+1
print "quotient:", q, "reminder:", r
assert q == x and r == -x^2+x*y^3-y+1
```

Output:

```
quotient: x reminder: x^2*y - x^2 - y + 1
quotient: 0 reminder: x^2*y - x^2 - y + 1

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-861e8a9d1112> in <module>()
     10 (q, r) = r.quo_rem(f2) # error, expected q = x, r = -x^2+x*y^3-y+1
     11 print "quotient:", q, "reminder:", r
---> 12 assert q == x and r == -x**Integer(2)+x*y**Integer(3)-y+Integer(1)

AssertionError:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Division of multivariate polynomials: term orders

The result of division of multivariable polynomials depends on the chosen order of monomials, as is [explained in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis#Reduction). For the present, it suffices to say that the quotient from dividing P by Q is nonzero if and only if P contains a monomial that is divisible by the leading monomial of Q *with respect to the chosen order*.

By default, polynomial rings in Sage use the degree-reverse lexicographic order (degrevlex for short), in which monomials are first sorted by total degree, and then lexicographically within each degree. You can check this by using `R.term_order()`. And here is [the list of term orders](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/polynomial_rings/sage/rings/polynomial/term_order.html).

In the degrevlex order, y^3 precedes x*y because it has higher total degree. And since x^2*y-x^2-y+1 does not have a monomial divisible by y^3, you get zero quotient.

#### Buggy quo_rem

Your expected results are consistent with the lexicographic (lex) order of monomials. So, it would seem that the fix is to prescribe lexicographic term order when constructing R:

```
R.<x,y> = PolynomialRing(QQ, 2, 'xy', order='lex')
```

Unfortunately, `quo_rem` ignores the term order of R and still uses degrevlex. This appears to be a bug, either in the way Sage communicates with Singular, or in Singular itself ([the Quotient command is deprecated](https://www.singular.uni-kl.de/Manual/4-0-2/sing_1703.htm)).

#### Workaround

Meanwhile, there is a workaround: use the `reduce` command instead of `quo_rem`, as it respects the term order   of R. For example:

```
R.<x,y> = PolynomialRing(QQ, 2, 'xy', order='lex')
a = x^2*y-x^2-y+1
f2 = x*y-y^3
r = a.reduce(Ideal([f2]))
q = (a-r)/f2
```

This returns r = -x^2 + x*y^3 - y + 1 and q = x.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I tried lexicographic order (one of the several things I tried), but with no effect. Very good to know that it's a bug! Thanks for the illustration of the workaround.