# Remainder sequences

Tags: math, sympy, polynomial-math, polynomials

I would like to compute the remainder sequence of two polynomials as used by GCD. If I understood the Wikipedia article about [Pseudo-remainder sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor#Subresultant_sequence_with_pseudo-remainders), one way to compute it is to use Euclid's algorithm:

```
gcd(a, b) := if b = 0 then a else gcd(b, rem(a, b))
```

meaning I will collect that `rem()` parts. If however the coefficients are integers, the intermediate fractions grow very quickly so then there are the so-called "Pseudo-remainder sequences" which try to keep the coefficients in small integers.

My question is, if I understood correctly (did I?), the two above sequences differ only by constant factor but when I try to run the following example I get different results, why? The first remainder sequence differs by `-2`, ok, but why is the second sequence so different? I presume `subresultants()` works correctly, but why does that `g % (f % g)` not work?

```
f = Poly(x**2*y + x**2 - 5*x*y + 2*x + 1, x, y)
g = Poly(2*x**2 - 12*x + 1, x)
print
print subresultants(f, g)[2]
print subresultants(f, g)[3]
print
print f % g
print g % (f % g)
```

which results in

```
Poly(-2*x*y - 16*x + y - 1, x, y, domain='ZZ')
Poly(-9*y**2 - 54*y + 225, x, y, domain='ZZ')

Poly(x*y + 8*x - 1/2*y + 1/2, x, y, domain='QQ')
Poly(2*x**2 - 12*x + 1, x, y, domain='QQ')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the two above sequences differ only by constant factor

For polynomials of **one** variable, they do. For multivariate polynomials, they don't.

The division of multivariable polynomials is a [somewhat tricky business](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35237836): result depends on the chosen order of monomials (by default, sympy uses lexicographic order). When you ask it to divide `2*x**2 - 12*x + 1` by `x*y + 8*x - 1/2*y + 1/2`, it observes that the leading monomial of the denominator is `x*y`, and there is no monomial in the numerator that is divisible by `x*y`. So the quotient is zero, and everything is a remainder.

The computation of subresultants (as it's implemented in sympy) treats polynomials in x,y as single-variable polynomials in x whose coefficients happen to come from the ring of polynomials in y. It is certain to produce a sequence of subresultants whose degree with respect to x keeps decreasing until it reaches 0: the last polynomial of the sequence will not have x in it. The degree with respect to y may (and does) go up, since the algorithm has no problem multiplying the terms by any polynomials in y in order to get x to drop out.

The upshot is that both computations work correctly, they just do different things.